# How to construct "chained" lists of length n

Tags: prolog

How do I generalise the following statements to construct any chained list `L` of length `n`.

```
list(1,S1,S2,L) :-
  L = [[S1,S2]]].
list(2,S1,S2,L) :-
  L = [[S1,S3]],[S3,S2]]].
list(3,S1,S2,L) :-
  L = [[S1,S3]],[S3,S4]],[S4,S2]]].
list(4,S1,S2,L) :-
  L = [[S1,S3]],[S3,S4]],[S4,S5]],[S5,S2]]].
list(5,S1,S2,L) :-
  L = [[S1,S3]],[S3,S4]],[S4,S5]],[S5,S6],[S6,S2]]].
```

Comment: Does it make sense that `list(0, S1,S2,L)` fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
chain(N, S0, S, Ls) :-
    length(Ls, N),
    chain_(Ls, S0, S).

chain_([], S, S).
chain_([[S0,S1]|Ls], S0, S) :-
    chain_(Ls, S1, S).
```

Or equivalently, using `foldl/4`:

```
chain(N, S0, S, Ls) :-
    length(Ls, N),
    foldl(chain_, Ls, S0, S).

chain_([S0,S], S0, S).
```

Example query:

```
?-  chain(3, S0, S, Ls).
Ls = [[S0, _G1584], [_G1584, _G1593], [_G1593, S]].
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list(1,S1,S2,[[S1,S2]]).
list(N,S1,S2,[[S1,S]|T]) :-
    N > 1,
    M is N-1,
    list(M,S,S2,T).
```

test:

```
?- list(3, S0, S, Ls).
Ls = [[S0, _G2824], [_G2824, _G2833], [_G2833, S]]
```